# What is the potential associated to a pure torque proportional to one of the principal axis of a particle?

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics, molecular-dynamics

I'm writing a code in molecular dynamics in which a particle is subject to a pure torque around one of its principal axis. E.g., if the particle has principle axis $\hat u$, $\hat v$, $\hat f$, all perpendicular to each other and such that $\hat u \times \hat v = \hat f$, The particle feels a torque

$\tau = \lambda \hat u$

with some constant $\lambda$. Can a potential which yields this torque be constructed? What is it?

Note that $\vec \tau$ is not a force, but torque. Therefore, a torque $\tau$ can be said to derive from a potential $U$ when the following holds:
$$
\vec \tau = - \sum_m \hat a_m \times \frac{\partial U}{\partial \hat a_m}
$$
for some reference frame ${\hat a_m}$.
E.g., the potential $ U = -J \hat f \cdot \hat z$ yields the torque $- J\hat z \times \hat f$
See for example equation (2) in http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0608387

EDIT: following mr blick's answer, I added a clarification of what does it mean to find a torque from a potential.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah because the torque is curl-free, so it can be written as the gradient of some potential. By inspection, the field $f(u)=-\lambda u$ satisfies the given torque, since $-\nabla f=\lambda \hat{u}=\vec{\tau}$.

Comment: Thanks but this would be true if $\tau$ was a force, not a torque. See my edit above.